# phpMyAdmin Access denied

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

phpMyAdmin give this error.

MySQL said:

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
>   phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: You probably used the wrong password.

Comment: well, the password is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe you should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server for real.

Comment: Man ... a piece of suggestion. Make a new user with all priveleges. use that account to login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to set:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true
```

in apps/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe try using no password ? By default password for root isn't set. If you are on linux try resetting the password by directly accessing the mysqldb. Maybe this link can help :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=227704