# How to fix 'Access Denied' message of phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Every time I start my laptop after shutdown, I need to re-install XAMPP to fix this problem of 'Access Denied' with several other errors(shown in uploaded photo). Restarting the servers from XAMPP won't change anything. What is the real reason behind it and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin Access denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483518/phpmyadmin-access-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin, int this folder there is a file "config.inc.php". Open this file in Notepad++ or Sublime Text or any text editor.

Add these 2 codes below this code:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Add the below code:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
```

Restart your xampp and it will work

Mine xampp config code is below:

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; //What you want

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Local Databases';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

// Hidden databases in PhpMyAdmin left panel
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys)';

// Allow connection without password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

// Suppress Warning about pmadb tables
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;

// To have PRIMARY & INDEX in table structure export
//$cfg['Export']['sql_drop_table'] = true;
//$cfg['Export']['sql_if_not_exists'] = true;

$cfg['MySQLManualBase'] = 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/';
/* End of servers configuration */

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin`, in this folder there is a file named `config.inc.php`. Open this file in Notepad++ or Sublime Text or any text editor.
If you add any password, then type the password in it. E.g. my password is `mysql123`, the config line has to be:

```php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mysql123';
```